# Number of ways to arrange $n$ numbered vertices in a simple undirected cycle.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations

I thought it'd be $(n-1)!$ and I've been told it's $(n-1)!/2$ because of a mirror like effect. Can anyone please explain this to me? I can't seem to get the hang of this.
Thank you :)

Comment: I think the word "undirected" might mean $(123)$ is the same as $(321)$.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this: If you visited each vertex along a path in a particular order, there would be $n!$ possible paths. Once you form an ordered cycle, all 'shifts' of that cycle are equivalent. If the cycle is unordered, going each direction around the cycle is also equivalent.

Let's say you have four vertices. There are 4! = 24 possible ordered paths through these vertices.

When you form a cycle, sets of 4 paths become equivalent. So these are all the same cycle:

1,2,3,4; 2,3,4,1; 3,4,1,2; 4,1,2,3

You have $n!/n = (n-1)!$ ordered cycles.

For an undordered cycle, the following are all equivalent:

1,2,3,4; 2,3,4,1; 3,4,1,2; 4,1,2,3

4,3,2,1; 3,2,1,4; 2,1,4,3; 1,4,3,2

You now have $(n-1)!/2$ unordered cycles.

Comment: True, but $n<3$ isn't really a cycle.